# flask query datetime and integer values

Tags: python, mysql, flask

How should I query for integer values and datetime object?
I'd like to insert post data when a post is submitted.
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        print(data)
        title = data['title']
        content = data['content']
        username = data['username']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(
            "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '{0}' LIMIT 1".format(username))
        authorID = cur.fetchone()['id']
        print(datetime.now())
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts(authorID, username, title, content, createdAt) VALUES ({}, {}, {},{},{})".format(
            authorID, username, title, content, datetime.now()))
```

Comment: How does it not work, can you show some error message?

Comment: In order to understand please share: 1. Error message. 2: HTML form. 3, Database config. 4.Full Flask route